# Stuck on recursion algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I got a question about recursion for an entry exam of a job, but I failed to do it within 2 hours. I am very curious about how to do this after the pre-exam but I cannot work out a solution.

You can imagine there is a coin pusher with size n*m (2D array).
Each operation (moving up or down or left or right) will throw away one row or one column of coins

The question requires me to find the shortest possible moves that remains k coins at last. If it is impossible to remain k coins at last, then return -1

I stuck on how to determine the next move when there is more than one operation that having the same maximum number of coins (same value to be thrown away)

I believe that I need to calculate recursively that simulates all future possible moves to determine the current move operation.

But I do not know how to implement this algorithm, can anyone help?

Thank you!

```
Question : 
There is a rectangular chessboard containing N‘M cells. each of
which either has one coin or nothing.
You can move all the coins together in one direction (such as up,
down, left, and right), but each time you can move these coins by
only one cell.

If any coins fall out of the chessboard, they must be thrown away.
If it is required to keep K coins on the board, what is the minimum
moves you have to take?

Output -1 if you can not meet this requirement.

The first line of the input are two positive 
integers n, representing the size of the board.

For the next n line(s), each line has m numbers of 
characters, with 'o' indicating a coin, '.' indicates an empty grid.

The last line is a positive integer k, 
indicating the number of coins to be retained.

30% small input: 1 <= n,m <= 5, 0 < k < 25
40% medium input: 1 <= n,m <= 10, 0 < k < 100
30% large input: 1 <= n,m <= 100, 0 < k < 10000

sample input:
3 4
.o..
oooo
..o.
3

sample output:
2
```

My temporary answer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    String[][] inputArray;

    int n;
    int m;
    int k;

    int totalCoin = 0;
    int step = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main temp = new main();
        temp.readData();
    }

    public void readData() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        m = sc.nextInt();
        inputArray = new String [n][m];

        sc.nextLine(); // skipping

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String temp = sc.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if ((temp.charAt(j) + "").equals("o")) totalCoin++;
                inputArray[i][j] = temp.charAt(j) + "";
            }
        }

        k = sc.nextInt();   
        int result = 0;

        if (totalCoin >= k) {
            result = findMaxAndMove();
            System.out.println(result);

        }

    }

    public String findNextMove() {
        Map<String,Integer> tempList = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        tempList.put("up", up());
        tempList.put("down", down());
        tempList.put("left", left());
        tempList.put("right", right());

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;


        for (Entry<String,Integer> temp : tempList.entrySet()) {
            if (maxEntry == null || temp.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue()) {
                maxEntry = temp;
            }
        }

        Map<String,Integer> maxList = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for (Entry<String,Integer> temp : tempList.entrySet()) {
            if (temp.getValue() == maxEntry.getValue()) {
                maxList.put(temp.getKey(), temp.getValue());
            }
        }

//      return maxList.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();

        if (maxList.size() > 1) {
            // how to handle this case when more than 1 operations has the same max value???????????
            return ??????????????
        }
        else {
            return maxList.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();
        }



//      


    }

    public int findMaxAndMove() {

        int up = up();
        int down = down();
        int left = left();
        int right = right();

        if ((totalCoin - up) == k) {
            step++;
            return step;
        }

        if ((totalCoin - down) == k) {
            step++;
            return step;
        }

        if ((totalCoin - left) == k) {
            step++;
            return step;
        }

        if ((totalCoin - right) == k) {
            step++;
            return step;
        }

        if (totalCoin - up < k && totalCoin - down < k && totalCoin - left < k && totalCoin - right < k) return -1;
        else {
            switch (findNextMove()) {
                case "up" :
                    totalCoin -= up;
                    this.moveUp();
                    break;
                case "down" :
                    totalCoin -= down;
                    this.moveDown();
                    break;
                case "left" :
                    totalCoin -= left;
                    this.moveLeft();
                    break;
                case "right" :
                    totalCoin -= right();
                    this.moveRight();
                    break;
            }
            step++;
            return findMaxAndMove(); // going to next move
        }

    }

    public String[] createBlankRow() {
        String[] temp = new String[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            temp[i] = ".";
        }
        return temp;
    }


    public int up() {
        int coinCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (inputArray[0][i].equals("o")) {
                coinCounter++;
            }
        }


        return coinCounter;
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        // going up
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i + 1];
        }

        inputArray[n-1] = createBlankRow();

    }

    public int down() {
        int coinCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (inputArray[n-1][i].equals("o")) {
                coinCounter++;
            }
        }


        return coinCounter;
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        // going down
        for (int i = n-1; i > 1; i--) {
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i - 1];
        }

        inputArray[0] = createBlankRow();


    }

    public int left() {
        int coinCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i][0].equals("o")) {
                coinCounter++;
            }
        }

        return coinCounter;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        // going left
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m-1; j++) {
                inputArray[i][j] = inputArray[i][j+1];
            }
            inputArray[i][m-1] = ".";

        }


    }


    public int right() {
        int coinCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i][m-1].equals("o")) {
                coinCounter++;
            }
        }

        return coinCounter;
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        // going right
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = m-1; j > 0; j--) {
                inputArray[i][j] = inputArray[i][j-1];
            }
            inputArray[i][0] = ".";
        }


    }



    public void printboard() {
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(inputArray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the question instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: also it is not quite clear to me what the question is

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  You need to be far more specific about what help you need.

Comment: Originally I want to make my algorithm working, but now I find that my algorithm is wrong for this question!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you didn't find the right algorithm to solve the problem. To find a solution, not only the reachable boards with some special coin count are of concern but all. You must build up a tree of reachable boards. Each node in this tree is connected to its child nodes by an operation. That's were recursion enters the scene. You stop

- when you reach your goal (mark this branch as possible solution) or
- when it got impossible to reach the goal with further operations (too few coins left)
- when the next operation would reach a board already visited in this branch.

In this tree all shortest branches marked as possible solution are the actual solutions. If no branch is marked as possible solution there is no solution and you have to output `-1`.

Comment: Yes， I think my algorithm cannot solve all cases. I am confused of how to start the recursion. For my clarification, is your algorithm calculating all possible branches (In the entry point, there are four roots including up, down, left and right, and each root has their four childs...., stop when meeting your three conditions) I wonder how can I collect all the result branches when the recursion is finished?

Comment: and also I don't understand what "when the next operation would reach a board already visited in this branch" means. How will the next operation possible to reach a board that already visited in this branch??

Comment: Simple case: If you perform one operation (for example `up`) without tossing a coin you may not perform the contrary operation (for example `down`) because this would produce lead to the board before operation one and would introduce an infinite recursion. There are more complex cases. The general rule is not to revisit already visited boards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
public class CoinsMover {


public static List<String> getMinMoves(Character[][] board, int k, List<String> moves) {

    if (!movesAreValid(moves, board)) {
        return null;
    }

    int currentAmountOfCoins = getCoinsOnBoard(board);

    // All good no need to move any thing
    if (currentAmountOfCoins == k) {
        moves.add("done");
        return moves;
    }

    // Moved to much wrong way
    if (currentAmountOfCoins < k) {
        return null;
    }


    List<String> moveRight = getMinMoves(moveRight(board), k, getArrayWithApendded(moves, "right"));
    List<String> moveLeft = getMinMoves(moveLeft(board), k, getArrayWithApendded(moves, "left"));
    List<String> moveUp = getMinMoves(moveUp(board), k, getArrayWithApendded(moves, "up"));
    List<String> moveDown = getMinMoves(moveDown(board), k, getArrayWithApendded(moves, "down"));

    List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    if (moveRight != null) {
        results.add(moveRight);
    }

    if (moveLeft != null) {
        results.add(moveLeft);
    }

    if (moveUp != null) {
        results.add(moveUp);
    }

    if (moveDown != null) {
        results.add(moveDown);
    }

    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    List<String> result = results.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size)).findFirst().get();

    return result;
}

private static boolean movesAreValid(List<String> moves, Character[][] board) {
    long ups = moves.stream().filter(m -> m.equals("up")).count();
    long downs = moves.stream().filter(m -> m.equals("down")).count();
    long lefts = moves.stream().filter(m -> m.equals("left")).count();
    long rights = moves.stream().filter(m -> m.equals("right")).count();

    boolean verticalIsFine = ups <= board.length && downs <= board.length;
    boolean horizontalIsFine = lefts <= board[0].length && rights <= board[0].length;
    return verticalIsFine && horizontalIsFine;
}

private static List<String> getArrayWithApendded(List<String> moves, String move) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(moves);
    result.add(move);
    return result;
}

private static Character[][] moveRight(Character[][] board) {
    Character result[][] = new Character[board.length][board[0].length];
    // Cleaning left column
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        result[i][0] = '.';

    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < board[row].length - 1; column++) {
            result[row][column + 1] = board[row][column];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static Character[][] moveLeft(Character[][] board) {
    Character result[][] = new Character[board.length][board[0].length];
    // Cleaning right column
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        result[i][board[i].length - 1] = '.';

    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column < board[row].length; column++) {
            result[row][column - 1] = board[row][column];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static Character[][] moveDown(Character[][] board) {
    Character result[][] = new Character[board.length][board[0].length];
    // Cleaning upper row
    for (int i = 0; i < board[board.length - 1].length; i++)
        result[0][i] = '.';

    for (int row = board.length - 1; row > 0; row--) {
        result[row] = board[row - 1];
    }

    return result;
}

private static Character[][] moveUp(Character[][] board) {
    Character result[][] = new Character[board.length][board[0].length];
    // Cleaning upper row
    for (int i = 0; i < board[board.length - 1].length; i++)
        result[board.length - 1][i] = '.';

    for (int row = 0; row < board.length - 1; row++) {
        result[row] = board[row + 1];
    }

    return result;
}

private static int getCoinsOnBoard(Character[][] board) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 'o') {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Character[][] mat = {{'.', 'o', '.', '.'}, {'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'}, {'.', '.', 'o', '.'}};
    List<String> result = getMinMoves(mat, 3, new ArrayList<>());
    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println(-1);//output [right, right, done]
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

I admit it was hard for me to search for duplicates so instead I am using a list of string which wrights the path you need to take to get to the solution. Now let's look at stopping condition first if current moves are invalid return null example of invalid moves is if you have a table with 4 columns in you moved right 5 times same goes for rows and moves up/down. Second, if board holds the neede amount we are done. And the last if board hold less we have failed. So now what algorithm is trying to do is to step in each direction in search of result and from here proceed recursivly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution below. A few points to note.

- Whenever you see a problem that mentions moving an array in 1 direction, it's always a good idea to define an array of possible directions and loop through it in the recursive function. This would prevent you from confusing yourself.
- The idea is to count coins by row and column so that you have a way to find out the remaining coins after each move in linear time.
- The remaining job is to just loop through the possible directions in your recursive functions to find a possible solution.
- As the recursive function may run in a circle and come back to one of the previous locations, you should/can improve the recursive function further by maintaining a `Map` cache of previous partial solutions using the `curRowIdx` and `curColIdx` as key.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] board = {{'.', 'o', '.', '.'},
                      {'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'},
                      {'.', '.', 'o', '.'}};

    CoinMoveSolver solver = new CoinMoveSolver(board);
    System.out.println(solver.getMinimumMove(3));
}

static class CoinMoveSolver {
    int[][] directions = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};
    char[][] board;
    int[] rowCount;
    int[] colCount;
    int height;
    int width;
    int totalCoins;

    public CoinMoveSolver(char[][] board) {
        // Set up the board
        this.board  = board;
        this.height = board.length;
        this.width  = board[0].length;

        // Count how many coins we have per row,
        // per column and the total no. of coins
        this.rowCount = new int[height];
        this.colCount = new int[width];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < board.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < board[i].length ; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == 'o') {
                    this.rowCount[i]++;
                    this.colCount[j]++;
                    totalCoins++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of coins if the top left
    // corner of the board is at rowIdx and colIdx
    private int countCoins(int rowIdx, int colIdx) {
        int sumRow = 0;
        for (int i = rowIdx ; i < rowIdx + height ; i++) {
            if (i >= 0 && i < height)
                sumRow += rowCount[i];
        }

        int sumCol = 0;
        for (int j = colIdx ; j < colIdx + width ; j++) {
            if (j >= 0 && j < width)
                sumCol += colCount[j];
        }

        return Math.min(sumRow, sumCol);
    }

    public int getMinimumMove(int targetCoinCount) {
        if (totalCoins < targetCoinCount)
            return -1;
        else if (totalCoins == targetCoinCount)
            return 0;
        else
            return this.recursiveSolve(0, 0, -1, 0, targetCoinCount);
    }

    private boolean isOppositeDirection(int prevDirectionIdx, int curDirectionIdx) {
        if (prevDirectionIdx < 0)
            return false;
        else {
            int[] prevDirection = directions[prevDirectionIdx];
            int[] curDirection  = directions[curDirectionIdx];

            return prevDirection[0] + curDirection[0] + prevDirection[1] + curDirection[1] == 0;
        }
    }

    private int recursiveSolve(int curRowIdx, int curColIdx, int prevDirectionIdx, int moveCount, int targetCoinCount) {
        int minMove = -1;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < directions.length ; i++) {
            if (!this.isOppositeDirection(prevDirectionIdx, i)) {
                int[] direction = directions[i];

                int nextRowIdx = curRowIdx + direction[0];
                int nextColIdx = curColIdx + direction[1];
                int coinCount  = this.countCoins(nextRowIdx, nextColIdx);

                // If this move reduces too many coins, abandon
                if (coinCount < targetCoinCount)
                    continue;
                // If this move can get us the exact number of
                // coins we're looking for, break the loop
                else if (coinCount == targetCoinCount) {
                    minMove = moveCount + 1;
                    break;

                } else {
                    // Look for the potential answer by moving the board in 1 of the 4 directions
                    int potentialMin = this.recursiveSolve(nextRowIdx, nextColIdx, i, moveCount + 1, targetCoinCount);
                    if (potentialMin > 0 && (minMove < 0 || potentialMin < minMove))
                        minMove = potentialMin;
                }
            }
        }

        // If minMove is still < 0, that means
        // there's no solution
        if (minMove < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return minMove;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i want to ask how the countCoins function work?? Why is the smaller value one of sumRow and sumCol is the result?? thanks

Comment: @gm292347 at the top of my solution, there's a sample board. Start with rowIdx 0 and colIdx 0 and I think you can visualize why :D